# How to create a navigation bar that fades in when user scrolls down? (on blogspot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

Okay, total noob here.
I have a blog on a blogspot platform, and I'm trying to create a navbar that fades in when the user is scrolling down. I've made my navbar in flash, put it in the right place, made it transparent and fixed etc. It is a div. I've no idea what code to use and where exactly to put it to make it fade-in on scroll down. HELP :D
http://blackforestdesigns.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this code just before `</body>`.

```
<script>
var navbar = document.querySelector('.sticknav');
navbar.style.opacity = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if(scrollTop > 400) {
        navbar.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    else {
        navbar.style.opacity = 0;
    }
});
</script>
```

If you want to get more adventurous, make a CSS class that animates the transition:

```
<style type="text/css">
.sticknav {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease;
}
.sticknav.is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

And replace the if/else above with:

```
if(scrollTop > 400) {
    navbar.classList.add('is-visible');
}
else {
    navbar.classList.remove('is-visible');
}
```

Comment: where exactly should I put this?

Comment: imcg3 I'm sorry, I have nooooo idea what you're talking about:)

Comment: so I've added the code above the </body> between script tags. Nothing happened.

Comment: added what @imcg suggested above the closing body tag, and this above closing body tag, and this is the code of my navbar, but nothing seems to happen: `<center>
<div class="sticknav">
<div style="position: fixed; align:top-center; z-index: 999999; param name="wmode" value="transparent"><embed pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" width="1118" height="72"   
wmode="transparent" src="https://c126a123-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/hautedomain/STICKY.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always"></embed></div></div></center>`

Comment: thanks so much for trying to help, but nothing seems to happen :(

Comment: omg, it's actually working! What do I need to change to make it fade-in instead of out, and can I control when exactly (after how many pixels scrolled down) does it fade in? Thank you so much!

Comment: thanks! It's working now, but every time I load my page, at the beginning it is visible, then on scrolling down it abruptly disappears and reappears again after I've scrolled down 400px. I want it to appear after 400px, but not to appear at the beginning, can you help me with this last bit? I'm so so thankful!

Comment: I changed the htlm to is hidden but you can still see it when the page loads the first time. Maybe I'm not putting the html in the right place? I put it above the </body>

Comment: the new version should do it. make sure you changed both the css and javascript.